# How can I insert multiple profiles resulting from a LPA as mediators in a mediation analysis?

Tags: r, posterior, latent-variable, mediation

I'm currently writing my master thesis and I'm a little stuck at one step of the data analysis process. Maybe you can help me:

I'm going to do a Latent Profile Analysis with 12 continuous variables in R resulting in multiple profiles (I guess 1-3). I want to use these profiles in a mediation analysis as mediators. But now I'm not sure how to insert the profiles in the mediation analysis. Do I use a (kind of a dummy) variable "Class" indicating the profile the participants are assigend to ranging from 1-3? But then I will loose information, right?! Or do I use all 12 variables as single mediators? This might get messy... A third option is to use the posterior probabilities resulting from the Latent Profile Analysis but I do not know how to use them as mediators exactly.

Do you have any recommendations or further ideas concerning this topic? This would be really helpful!!

Thanks in advance and lovely day

Marie